# How to check if a column has a particular Date format or not using DATETIME in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, date, datetime, date-formatting

I am new to python. I have a data-frame which has a date column in it, it has different formats. I would like to check if it is following particular date format or not. I it is not following I want to drop it. I have tried using try except and iterating over the rows. But I am looking for a faster way to check if the column is following a particular date format or not. `If it is not following then it has to drop. Is there any faster way to do it? Using DATE TIME library?`

```
My code:
Date_format = %Y%m%d
df =
    Date       abc
0  2020-03-22  q
1  03-12-2020  w
2  55552020    e
3  25122020    r
4  12/25/2020  r
5  1212202033  y

Excepted out:
 Date       abc
0  2020-03-22  q
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce')
0   2020-03-22
1   2020-03-12
2          NaT
3          NaT
4   2020-12-25
5          NaT
```

It's easy to drop the null values then

EDIT:
For a given format you can still leverage `pd.to_datetime`:

```
datetimes = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')
datetimes
0   2020-03-22
1          NaT
2          NaT
3          NaT
4          NaT
5          NaT


df.loc[datetimes.notnull()]
```

Also note I am using the format `%Y-%m-%d` which I think is the one you want based on your expected output (not the one you gave as `Date_format`)

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this. I don't want to change the format, I just want check if they are in a particular pattern. Oh shit! I forgot to add the format. Please re-check it. I have updated